# How to disconnect from lxc-console

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lxc

I'm working with lxc in Ubuntu 12.04, and it's really great. However, I am unable to disconnect from a `lxc-console` session after I've connected. I read somewhere that <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> will disconnect me from the console but it doesn't seem to work.

Should I be running `lxc-console` via `screen` instead?

Comment: I have the same issue.  If you start a container forgetting the "-d" parameter, there is no way out.  Ctrl a q has no effect.  The only solution I have found is to login to the console, and do "sudo poweroff", that gets you out.

Comment: you can also do an `lxc-stop` from another shell

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes, <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>, should work by default, however no, `lxc-console` does not actually use `screen` to accomplish its console behavior. In fact, you might be encountering a conflict if you are using screen since it also uses <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> as a prefix. If you're inside `screen` but don't realize it then you'll need to type <kbd>Ctrl-a a q</kbd> since the default behavior of `screen` is that you have to type <kbd>Ctrl-a a</kbd> to actually send `^a` to the shell running inside of it. You can change the prefix for escape by passing the `-e` or `--escape=PREFIX` option to `lxc-console`.

Also, it appears there may be a bug in `lxc-start` so that if it immediately goes into console mode when you start the container you can't using <kbd>Ctrl-a q</kbd> to escape-- in fact, all the control characters seem to be screwed up and print to the screen instead of behaving the way you expect. One workaround is to run it with the `-d` or `--daemon` option so that it doesn't immediately start a console, and the connect to it by hand:

```
lxc-start -d -n container-name
lxc-console -n container-name
```

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl-a q</kdb> does not have any effect on a connected console with lxc version 0.9.0

Comment: if the lxc devs should ever wonder why docker had a billion times higher adoption, this bug is one of the main reasons.

Comment: @FlorianHeigl While I agree with your sentiment about this bug being ugly, the true reasons for that are attitudes:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768073
https://access.redhat.com/articles/1365153
https://access.redhat.com/discussions/2772171 (and numerous other occasions where RedHat responds to "LX(C|D)?" with "No, Docker!" (note that these are top Google results for "LXD Debian", and "LXD Redhat queries").

Answer (score 4):

What I did to stop the container

1. Open a new session.
2. Login as root.
3. Check the container status.
4. `lxc-stop -n <name of the container>`

This will stop the container.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it connect via `screen`?  `Ctrl-a d` should get you out of it.

The [Ubuntu LXC page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LXC) has more information.

Comment: No, this does not work. I've been using screen so that I can disconnect from lxc-console. Also, the link that you posted does not have any information about this problem.

Comment: "Detach screen: C-a d or C-a C-d" - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LXC#Mini_screen_how-to; not sure what to do if that's not working.

Comment: @ElYobo No, `lxc-console` does not actually use `screen`, it just has similar behavior and by default actually uses a key that conflicts with `screen`'s as [described here](http://serverfault.com/a/438824/93109).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to login is to just do `ssh <ip>` instaed of using `lxc-console`. You could use start it as daemon using `lxc-start -d -n <name>` and then login using console to get the IP for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when working with my Trusty LXC in Xenial-host and after starting the container with `lxc-start -F -n CN` couldn't get out and back to host when logged out from the container. Also the `sudo lxc-ls -f`in the host hanged and none of the `lxc-stop`commands with -k or -W or --no-lock options worked, so I eventually kill -9'd the container process which worked but afterwards starting the container with `lxc-start` or `lxc-attach`do not work properly, but display errors about  lxc_cgfsng and not finding the init pid etc.

See more here: https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/1195

Answer (score -6):

When you are done working with some application you can usually terminate it witch CTR+C. If that doesn't do the trick, there is always the quit command: CTRL+.

CTRL+D, on the other hand means "END OF FILE", and works usually to stop some program from reading the keyboard. You can log out of regular shell with CTRL+D.