# Byobu - How to disconnect from lxc-console

Tags: gnu-screen, lxc, byobu

I am inside Byobu on ubuntu 12.04 and entered an lxc-console. Unfortunately, the escape sequence for lxc appears to be `cntrl-a q`. However this clashes with Byobu's which also uses `cntrl-a` sequence. I tried [this questions answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/405482/how-to-disconnect-from-lxc-console) of using `cntrl-a a q`, but it appears that `cntrl-a a` tries to go to the next window in byobu! I also tried changing the escape sequence by using f9, but it appears that this is broken as it does not change from `cntrl-a`. What is the solution other than killing the container from outside that screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open up a second connection to an other *tty*.

Then you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd> to kill the `screen` window you are trapped in.

---

To prevent this from happening for consecutive sessions you can define the escape character to e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>:

```
# lxc-console -e '^e' -n containername
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102640/how-do-i-send-a-literal-f6-etc-in-byobu), you can:

Send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (enters the BYOBU command area), then, <kbd>a</kbd> to drop into the lxc-console command area, then <kbd>q</kbd> to quit the lxc console.